# PostgreSQL query by JSON object in array

Tags: sql, json, database, postgresql, jsonb

Folks,

I have a following table in my PostgreSQL.

```
CREATE TABLE public.my_table
(
    id uuid NOT NULL,
    name character varying(50) NOT NULL,
    field1 jsonb NOT NULL
)
```

I keep JSON array in my field1 as per example below:

```
[
    {
        "id": "abc"
    },
    {
        "id": "def"
    },
    {
        "id": "ghi"
    }
]
```

My question is:
How do I query for rows that include a specific "id" in that JSON array?

Thanks for your help!
Cheers!

Comment: could you show us sample data in tabular form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the contains operator:

```
select * from my_table where field1 @> '[{"id":"whatever"}]'
```

This operation is able to make use of an index on field1, while a method that relies on jsonb_array_elements cannot be indexed.

Comment: This is even better than the one from @GMB. I love it! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

One option uses `exists` and `jsonb_array_elements()`:

```
select *
from my_table t
where exists (
    select 1 from jsonb_array_elements(t.field1) f(obj) where f.obj ->> 'id' = 'abc'
)
```

Comment: Great stuff! That's what I need. Thx mate!